# Jquery XML parse skip data elements/nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am displaying some data from an XML using jquery but I want it to skip some elements/nodes and start at a different point rather than the beginning, is this even possible? heres the code im using below.

```
var xml = "<alldata><data><datatext>data one</datatext></data><data><datatext>data two</datatext></data><data><datatext>data three</datatext></data><data><datatext>data four</datatext></data><data><datatext>data five</datatext></data></alldata>";
var $xml = $($.parseXML( xml ));

var datatext = $xml.find("data");

datatext.each(function(){
$('body').append($(this).find('datatext').text()+'<br>');
});
```

That would produce

```
data one
data two
data three
data four
data five
```

But I would like to skip the first 3, so it would only produce

```
data four
data five
```

Comment: what is the condition for skipping or directly start node from 4th?

Comment: @Ajay2707 becuase I am limiting my results to 5 per load, each time a load more button is pressed it gets 5 pieces of data from the xml file, I need to to skip ones its already got

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like `datatext = datatext.slice(3);`

It will give you `data four` and `data five`

**Demo**

```js
var xml = "<alldata><data><datatext>data one</datatext></data><data><datatext>data two</datatext></data><data><datatext>data three</datatext></data><data><datatext>data four</datatext></data><data><datatext>data five</datatext></data></alldata>";
var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));

var datatext = $xml.find("data");
datatext = datatext.slice(3);
datatext.each(function() {
  $('body').append($(this).find('datatext').text() + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first 3 `data` nodes you can call `slice()` on the `datatext` object before you loop through it:

```js
var xml = "<alldata><data><datatext>data one</datatext></data><data><datatext>data two</datatext></data><data><datatext>data three</datatext></data><data><datatext>data four</datatext></data><data><datatext>data five</datatext></data></alldata>";
var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));
var $datatext = $xml.find("data");

$datatext.slice(3).each(function() {
  $('body').append($(this).find('datatext').text() + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```